# How to use the strlen() with 2d array?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, strlen

I want to know the horizontal size of my 2D char array. I found strlen() for that, but it works only with a simple char array. With 2D it doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks for the answers!

```
char m[3][4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            m[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }

cout << "CHAR Matrix: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            cout << "[" << m[i][j] << "]";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

cout << "Sizeof matrix -> " << sizeof(m) << "B" << endl;

cout << "Length of Matrix strlen(m[0]): " << strlen(m[0]) << endl;
```

**The problem is that ,,strlen(m[0]),, gives me 18. How could i get 4?**

Comment: Did you try `sizeof` instead of `strlen`?

Comment: `strlen` is for null-terminated byte strings - which you don't have

Comment: From what I can see, `m[0]` is not a null-terminated string, hence, according to the documentation of [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen): "_The behavior is undefined if there is no null character in the character array pointed to by str._"

Comment: Use a `std::array` or a `std::vector` that knows its `.size()`. Forget that C-style arrays exist (or know they exist but *stop using them*). And please learn about rhe [standard algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) so you don't have to hand-roll stuff like your writing code in the previous century.

Comment: You could probably replace `m` with `vector<string>` or `array<string, 3>`. All of `vector`, `array`, and `string` have tons of helpful functions and safety checks built-in to save you from yourself, and they all work really cleanly with a ton of standard algorithms

Comment: @PavanManjunath Please don't write (or suggest others write) C++ by guessing.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I agree I should have added more details. But the idea was to veer OP towards looking up `sizeof` and see if it fits their needs themselves.

Comment: @PavanManjunath "the idea was to veer OP towards looking up sizeof and see if it fits their needs" - That is (IMHO) still steering them in the wrong direction. The *real* problem is the use of C-style arrays and use of C functions. There are *much better* ways to approach this in C++, if one just crawls out of the C mindset first.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things going on. Some of the comments above help, but let's go over it.

First, if you're using C++ and you're holding strings, you should use std::string. However, your problem indicates you're just learning, so let's stick to old-school C.

What you have allocated is a 2-dimensional array of single characters. That is, you are storing in total 12 characters of data.

In C (or C++) strings are null-terminated. That is, if you store as a string "Hi", it's actually 3 characters, not two. H, I, and a zero byte that indicates the end of the string.

strlen simply counts the number of characters until the zero byte. So in my example, 2.

You don't have any 0-bytes in your array, so strlen counts until it hits a zero due to some other reason -- completely outside your array. Yikes!

So... It's a mistake to use the string methods (strlen, strdup, etc) when dealing with single characters.

Now, the safest thing would be to use a vector of std::string, as others have suggested. However, I am a firm believer in understanding the basics before taking shortcuts, and that's a shortcut.

So if what you really want is 3 strings, but you want to use old-school C, then you should actually have a 1-dimensional array of char *.

```
char *m[3];
m[0] = "Hello";
m[1] = "there";
m[2] = "everyone";
```

It would be REALLY weird to store strings the way you have, and it's considered quite dangerous to use fixed-length character buffers for holding strings. This is where the infamous buffer overrun exploits come from, the most common exploits in old school web applications.

Alternatively, you could modify your example. make m[3][5], and store a zero-byte in each row after the end of your strings. strlen() will start to work. But it's really kind of ugly.